# How to access the data returned in an HTTPS response

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, rest, https

I'm trying to learn how to use an API through node.js. I'm using the starwars API to learn on. I am able to get a response back when using this code:

```
const https = require('https');
https.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/', (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

that looks like this:

```
`{"name":"Luke Skywalker","height":"172","mass":"77","hair_color":"blond","skin_color":"fair","eye_color":"blue","birth_year":"19BBY","gender":"male","homeworld":"https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/","films":["https://swapi.co/api/films/2/","https://swapi.co/api/films/6/","https://swapi.co/api/films/3/","https://swapi.co/api/films/1/","https://swapi.co/api/films/7/"],"species":["https://swapi.co/api/species/1/"],"vehicles":["https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/14/","https://swapi.co/api/vehicles/30/"],"starships":["https://swapi.co/api/starships/12/","https://swapi.co/api/starships/22/"],"created":"2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z","edited":"2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z","url":"https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"}`
```

I want to be able to do something like `console.log(body.name)` and have it print out "Luke Skywalker" but it prints out "undefined" instead. How can I access the data that's returned to me?

PS. Sorry if this is a duplicate question, it seems like the kind that would be. I've found a ton of questions that come very close to mine, but not quite answer it. I've also been through the [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) too, but that dealt more with how to make a request, not what to do with it. At least from what I got from it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to `JSON.parse` the string into an object first.

```
const https = require('https');
https.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/', (res) => {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function(body) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(obj.name);
  });
});
```

Comment: You're a saint!

Comment: I actually think I tried that using the pokemon API. I just tried out the exact same code, but with the url \"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/" instead but got `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`  I had previously switched to the starwars API on a whim. Does that mean the problem is on their end?

Comment: the url isnt displaying right because stack is auto-embedding it, but it does have the correct https:// head, and it does connect correctly and return data, just errors when I try to parse it with JSON.parse()

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/99kh7gr0/ Maybe you got the syntax wrong (remove "setEncoding" maybe?)

Comment: `const https = require('https');
    https.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/', (res) => {
        res.on('data', function (body) {
          const obj = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log(obj.name);
        });
    });`

gives the error
 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/davidsullivan/Desktop/Programing/JavaScript/Node/api-test/api-caller.js:5:24)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage........ (cut for char limit)

Comment: It's responding in parts, so like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/7klr5knlyx (just console.log and google and you can solve most problems)

Comment: That makes total sense. I've seen some other examples that included this too. thank you